# Which parts of a spring onion should I use in a pasta salad?

Tags: onions, salad

The recipe I've got ([Commonsense cooking](http://www.abbeys.com.au/book/commonsense-cooking.do), page 211) for a pasta salad lists spring onion ([green onion/scallions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/4556/4836)) as an ingredient, but doesn't say which part to use. Should I be using the long, slender green tops, or the small white bulb, or both?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using both is fine. I would reserve some of the green end to sprinkle on top for presentation. The white part is stronger so you may want to add it a little at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Well if i was you i would taste both parts of the spring onion and decide what will work best with your other flavors, you will find they have a notable difference in taste and texture..i would go with the green part 99% of the time

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Chives instead of spring onions. Green leaves of spring onions are mostly used for garnishing the pasta salads.

I use Chives mostly for the following reasons.

- Chives are less stronger in onion aroma
- Chive is tendor and has less pronounced onion flavor
- Less amount is required

Ofcourse both has their distinctive flavours and if you desire your dish should have the spring onion flavour then forget about Chives. Here what I mentioned is more for a garnishing/presentation point of view.

Answer (score 0):

The whole onion can be used, but I like the "spring" taste in the greens, so I use three parts finely-cut greens to one part whites.

Answer (score 0):

The whole springonion can be used, except for the roots.

The white parts are usually stronger in flavor, but have a more tender texture.
The green parts have a more subdued flavor, but are a bit crisper.

In older springonions the tip of the green part can become either limp, or dry and bitter, but the rest will usually still be usable.